# Create a new iOS project sized for smaller sized iPhone screens (4, 4s)

Tags: iphone, ios

This is driving me nuts, and I assume that it's something simple. I'm trying to create a new iOS 5.1 / iPhone 4 app with Xcode 4.5 and using my iPhone 5 for testing. I've made a new project with a storyboard and when I test it on my device, it scales to fill the screen - all of my images are stretched. I'd like to be fixed a the smaller screen sizes for older devices (4, 4s, etc.).

What settings on the view controller/view do I need to adjust to do this? Or is it in build settings?

Comment: Are you targetting the correct version of iOS?

Comment: Yes - in deployment, my iOS deployment target is iOS 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the allowed builds, in the Traget Build Settings, from the default `armv7 armv7s` to only `armv7` and delete the file: `Default-568h@2x.png`.

Comment: Is that in the "valid arch." section? I've set debug and release to only "armv7" there and deleted the default image and it's still not working.

Comment: You have to remove your previous project on the phone, by holding down your finger on the icon until it wiggles and then press the red icon and delete it. In simulator you do "Reset Contents and Settings"

Comment: Nope, still not solved. I've fixed the size of the UIView to 460px and that's fixed the scaling issue - but I can't get it to display in the "older app compatibility" mode that I was wanting. I did publish it to an iPhone 4 and it looks fine so at least that's not an issue.

Comment: This worked for me but only after I deleted the previous app from the device. Go through your folder and make sure Default-568h@2x.png is gone and clean the project, delete the app from the device and try again.

Comment: No dice over here. What kind of project did you start from? Empty app, single view, storyboard? Wondering if that has something to do it with?

Comment: I started from a project that had been adopted fully for iPhone5, thus it was not running in the frame. Then, I applied what I say above and it runs in the frame now. It should not matter what you start from. You just have to double check your settings and delete the file/app and restart the Xcode. It´s not really much more I can suggest unless you send me your whole xcode folder. You could make a new project and transfer your files into it.

Comment: I've tried this on several new projects and it works fine, been meaning to come back and mark it. Thanks for your help!